# Get item text from listbox

Tags: silverlight, listbox, listboxitem

I'm making a `UserControl` which uses a `ListBox`. In some moment I need to get the text of the selected item in the `ListBox`. The "normal" way I would go is:

```
var selected = (CustomObject)listBox.SelectedItem;
var str = selected.PropertyShowingInListBox;
```

But for some reasons of the `UserControl` I can't cast the `SelectedItem`. So my next chance is to get the text by reflection using the `SelectedItem` as `object` and `DisplayMemberPath`. Like this:

```
var selected = listBox.SelectedItem;
var str = selected.GetType().GetProperty(listBox.DisplayMemberPath).GetValue(selected, null).ToString();
```

But it isn't the best. Is there any way I use?

Comment: "But for some reasons of the `UserControl` I can't cast the `SelectedItem`."  What are these reasons you speak of?  Why can you not cast `SelectedItem` to `CustomObject`?

Comment: I didn't wrote this in the question because I don't think its pertinent. I make a generic view model which knows the type of this objects (`T`). But the view, as (AFAIK) it can't be generic so it doesn't know `T`. Continuing with my model, the view is specialized by each `T` I need with this UserControl assigning the DataContext to self. This specializations is what I'm really going to use.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, one thing you could do would be to create an interface implemented by objects that know how to be displayed in a ListBox.  This interface would contain a property such as `PropertyShowingInListBox`.  You would then make your view-model objects implement this interface, and in your code above you could cast to this interface instead of `CustomObject`.

Comment: That's a nice way! Thanks.